# error when adding a repository to install programs on ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu-16.04, atom-editor

I am trying to install the Atom to be able to develop my sites, but this is having some conflict at the moment that I try to add the repository. The following output is displayed:

```
    marcius@Marcius-PC:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/atom
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 335, in get_ppa_info
    ret = get_ppa_info_from_lp(user, ppa)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 92, in get_ppa_info_from_lp
    return get_info_from_lp(lp_url)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 88, in get_info_from_lp
    return _get_https_content_py3(lp_url)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 110, in _get_https_content_py3
    lp_page = urllib.request.urlopen(request, cafile=LAUNCHPAD_PPA_CERT)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 153, in urlopen
    capath=capath)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 470, in create_default_context
    context.load_verify_locations(cafile, capath, cadata)
ssl.SSLError: unknown error (_ssl.c:3053)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 122, in <module>
    shortcut = shortcut_handler(line)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 864, in shortcut_handler
    ret = factory(shortcut)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 407, in shortcut_handler
    return PPAShortcutHandler(shortcut)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 364, in __init__
    info = get_ppa_info(self.shortcut)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 347, in get_ppa_info
    _get_suggested_ppa_message(user, ppa))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 304, in _get_suggested_ppa_message
    lp_user = get_info_from_lp(LAUNCHPAD_USER_API % user)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 88, in get_info_from_lp
    return _get_https_content_py3(lp_url)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 110, in _get_https_content_py3
    lp_page = urllib.request.urlopen(request, cafile=LAUNCHPAD_PPA_CERT)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 153, in urlopen
    capath=capath)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 470, in create_default_context
    context.load_verify_locations(cafile, capath, cadata)
ssl.SSLError: unknown error (_ssl.c:3053)
marcius@Marcius-PC:~$
```

It seems to me that some problem with the dependencies of python, someone knows exactly what it is, and better how to correct?

Answer (score 4):

Removing all certs in `/usr/share/ca-certificates` and then reinstalling worked for me.

Try this:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/share/ca-certificates

sudo apt-get --reinstall install ca-certificates
```

Source: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2113326

Comment: Worked for me like a charm... :)

Comment: the only valid solution for me, thanks!